# Get the input value of a specific form with javascript when the submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a page with a number of similar forms and would like to get the value of the input fields, when I press the submit button. I tried this on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75gz9sfw/) and it seems to be working. When I try this on my website, it returns "undefined".

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <form action="editline.php" method="POST" class="editline">
        <input type="hidden" name="editID" class="form-control id" value="123456">
        <td data-label="Name"><textarea name="editName" class="form-control name" rows="1" autocomplete="off" required>Name1</textarea></td>
        <td data-label="Address"><input type="text" name="editAddress" class="form-control address" value="Address1" autocomplete="off" required></td>
        <td data-label="Colour"><input type="text" name="editColour" class="form-control colour" value="Colour1" autocomplete="off" required></td>
        <td data-label="Edit"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</button></td>
    </form>
</tr>
<tr>
    <form action="editline.php" method="POST" class="editline">
        <input type="hidden" name="editID" class="form-control id" value="987654">
        <td data-label="Name"><textarea name="editName" class="form-control name" rows="1" autocomplete="off" required>Name2</textarea></td>
        <td data-label="Address"><input type="text" name="editAddress" class="form-control address" value="Address2" autocomplete="off" required></td>
        <td data-label="Colour"><input type="text" name="editColour" class="form-control colour" value="Colour2" autocomplete="off" required></td>
        <td data-label="Edit"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</button></td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$('.editline').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).find('input.id').val();
    var name = $(this).find('textarea.name').val();
    var address = $(this).find('input.address').val();
    var colour = $(this).find('input.colour').val();

    alert(id + ' ' + name + ' ' + address + ' ' + colour);
});
```

Is it a problem, that the forms are in tables? Is there an other way to just get the input values of the form where the submit button has been pressed?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:// Okay, since the problem is caused by the form being in a table, is there a workaround? I'd like to use a table for this.

Edit2:// This JS is working great, when the forms are in a table ([FSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bg7o2cu4/)):

```
$('.editline').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id = tr.find('input.id').val();
    var name = tr.find('textarea.name').val();
    var address = tr.find('input.id').val();
    var colour = tr.find('input.colour').val();

    alert(id + ' ' + name + ' ' + address + ' ' + colour);
});
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: INVALID HTML. You can not have a form as a child of a TR, TDS are not a child of a FORM

Comment: @rv7 There are no errors in the console. The alert just gives me 4 times "undefined".

Comment: Looks fine to me...as you say it works in the fiddle, no good reason that it shouldn't work on your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only one form, then set the action to the button and get the closest line with it's inputs. Then ,in the click function you can call an ajax post to the form.

```js
$('.editline button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var id = tr.find('input.id').val();
  var name = tr.find('textarea.name').val();
  var address = tr.find('input.address').val();
  var colour = tr.find('input.colour').val();
  alert(id + ' ' + name + ' ' + address + ' ' + colour);
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="editline.php" method="POST" class="editline">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-label="Name"><input type="hidden" name="editID" class="form-control id" value="123456"><textarea name="editName" class="form-control name" rows="1" autocomplete="off" required>Name1</textarea></td>
    <td data-label="Address"><input type="text" name="editAddress" class="form-control address" value="Address1" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    <td data-label="Colour"><input type="text" name="editColour" class="form-control colour" value="Colour1" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    <td data-label="Edit"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-label="Name">
      <input type="hidden" name="editID" class="form-control id" value="987654">
      <textarea name="editName" class="form-control name" rows="1" autocomplete="off" required>Name2</textarea>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Address"><input type="text" name="editAddress" class="form-control address" value="Address2" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    <td data-label="Colour"><input type="text" name="editColour" class="form-control colour" value="Colour2" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    <td data-label="Edit"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the entire table in the form. This would solve the issue of invalid HTML.

```js
$('.editline').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).find('input.id').val();
    var name = $(this).find('textarea.name').val();
    var address = $(this).find('input.address').val();
    var colour = $(this).find('input.colour').val();

    alert(id + ' ' + name + ' ' + address + ' ' + colour);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="editline.php" method="POST" class="editline">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name"><textarea name="editName" class="form-control name" rows="1" autocomplete="off" required>Name2</textarea></td>
      <td data-label="Address"><input type="text" name="editAddress" class="form-control address" value="Address2" autocomplete="off" required></td>
      <td data-label="Colour"><input type="text" name="editColour" class="form-control colour" value="Colour2" autocomplete="off" required></td>
      <td data-label="Edit"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</button>     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <input type="hidden" name="editID" class="form-control id" value="987654">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

For example:

```js
function geti() {
  var i = document.getElementById('i').value;
  var iv = document.getElementById('iv');
  iv.innerHTML = i;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="i">
<button onclick="geti();">Click Me</button>
<p id="iv"></p>
```

Comment: The question asks about extracting values from a page with multiple `form` elements. This answer doesn't even have one `form` element in it.

Comment: But you can use this for more elements. Just think.

Comment: I've been "thinking" about HTML, CSS and JavaScript for over 20 years. Your answer doesn't include any description of what the problem or solution is, nor does it even address the question. You do understand that not every element will have an `id` (nor should elements have an `id` as a default way of identifying them), right? Read the question and you will see that the OP is using JQuery and the `.find()` method so your solution is not relevant.